# Default Selection Of An Item In A ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make an application in which there is a `ListView`. The problem is that I want it to show a default selection (i.e. 1st item should be selected by default in it; the selected item's background should be highlighted when it's selected). I am able to achieve this selected when the user chooses between the different listitems. But am not able to have a default selection when the listview opens up. Can anyone please help me out with this or suggest some tutorials for the same?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter code, inside the function

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Make a function call

```
convertView.setSelected(true)
```

for the position which you want to be showed as selected.